# Navigation list float reversed order on responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I'm having issues with my navbar. Read the code and try to give some solution if possible. Problem is that the logo goes to the left and the rest of the list goes right in reversed orded. I know I could change that in html, but then responsive changes order. When I look at it over the phone order is normal, if I change the html order, its normal on widescreen and reversed on phone and the other way around. Hope you guys understood what I wanted to say.

```css
ul.topnav .logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav .logo a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
r {
  color: #E53935;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .89);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
ul.topnav li {} ul.topnav li:first-child {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
  float: right;
}
ul.topnav li:first-child a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  color: #951717;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon a {
    font-size: 13px;
    ;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li:not(:last-child) a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 4px;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="logo">
    <a href="index.php">
      <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="active" href="about.php">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="coaching.php">COACHING</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="faqs.php">FAQS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: That's how `float: right` works. The first element goes all the way to the right, the next one goes to the left of it.